# How to encode a string in python3.6..?

Tags: python

My code is

```
import base64
var = "this is a program for string capitalize method"
var1 = base64.b64encode(bytes('var','utf-8'))
print("String Encode:",end=''),print(var1.encode('base64','strict'))
```

but I am getting the following error:

> AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: the error here is at it suggests.  'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'.
var1 is byte and byte object don't have encode method.

Comment: Thank you **advay**

Comment: Did you not already encode var1?

Comment: `print(var1)` instead.

Comment: Also, I think you mean to use `var` instead of the string `'var'`.

Comment: Thank you **Antti**

Answer (score 0):

Line 3 replace 'var' with var.
line 4 print var1 directly.

```
import base64
var = "this is a program for string capitalize method"
var1 = base64.b64encode(bytes(var,'utf-8')) # to encode above text
print("String Encode:",end=''),print(var1)) # var1 encoded string in bytes
```

Comment: Thanks **WSMathias9**